# how to install node.js in MACOS by using homebrew

Tags: homebrew, nodes

**If I write,
brew install node**

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "node".
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.

**If I write,
brew doctor**

```
Warning: Suspicious https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core git origin remote found.
The current git origin is:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't update properly.
You can solve this by setting the origin remote:
  git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
```

help me....I want to download node by using homebrew, and I want to solve all Warning.........

Comment: If you're planning any development, I recommend installing using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 16):

Just follow the instructions.

According to `brew doctor`, you have to run this command.

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

I just had the same issue. Once checked-out to `master`, install ran correctly.

Comment: Are you able to find the issue? what was that

Answer (score 4):

My solution is to remove homebrew/core and tap homebrew/core again.

follow these command:

First:

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
```

Second:

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Then just do the normal install process.

Comment: Note for people with slow internet: This answer should be used only as a last resort because homebrew/core has thousands of commits and consequently takes a long time to tap. My local clone of homebrew/core is 580 MB.

Comment: That worked for me too!
I am using a new Mac with nothing else install!